# Need help to make my program automated

Tags: linux, unix

I just wanted to get some idea how I should approach to this. I am trying to automate to get report back to a database with these bunch of scripts (i.e., java -jar snet_client.jar -mode report -id 13528 -props /int2/contact/client0.properties & ). Lets say I have hundreds of this command with unique numbers as it in the script(13528). I need to put that in a loop so that I do not need to write/copy&paste that hundred scripts over and over to execute. Any suggestion would be helpful. It has to be in unix.

Comment: Where is the `id` property coming from?

Comment: lets say i have those numbers in excel or in text file, and its unique numbers. I am thinking if I keep those numbers in a text file and read from each one at a time. For example: java -jar snet_client.jar -mode report -id 13528 -props /int2/contact/client0.properties & then next cycle would be java -jar snet_client.jar -mode report -id 12547 -props /int2/contact/client0.properties & then java -jar snet_client.jar -mode report -id 98728 -props /int2/contact/client0.properties & so on and so forth..

Comment: Do you need to put them in the background with `&` ? You can get problems (db locks, out of resources) and somebody might think of using `wait` to prevent that.

Comment: It was just I wanted them to work in the background since I am accessing a Linux machine by putty. If I need to log off that machine it wont close my end my program.

Answer (score 0):

This first bash script would iterate over each line in the file `textfile`, assuming that each of the `id` values are on a single line, start the java process and wait for it to complete before starting the next one.

```
# Queueing
# This one will only start the next process when the previous one completes.
OLD_IFS=$IFS
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line_data; do
    java -jar snet_client.jar -mode report -id ${line_data} -props /int2/contact/client0.properties &
    wait;
done < /path/to/textfile
IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

Alternatively, this script does the same, as far as getting `id` values from a text file, but doesn't wait for the first to complete before the next is started. This will likely cause problems is the `snet_client.jar` program is very resource intensive:

```
# Non-queueing
# This starts and runs all the processes
OLD_IFS=$IFS
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line_data; do
    java -jar snet_client.jar -mode report -id ${line_data} -props /int2/contact/client0.properties &
done < /path/to/textfile
IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

On both, we store the current `IFS` value before we begin so we can reset it after the process runs, just in case we need it set back for something later in the script file.

I have not tested these (since I don't have the dependencies available), so you might have to make adjustments for your own environment.

Comment: so, id numbers will be in a single line? any space in between or comma ?

Comment: @Rookie_Guy Each ID would have to be on a separate line for these solutions to work as they are written. If the IDs were on one line and separated by a comma followed by a space, the `IFS` would change from `$'\n' ` to `$', '`.

Comment: Ok, so let me understand the process. My ids(for example: 123433, 344223, 443422....) in a folder lets say /path/to/textfile.txt. How's this line_data is collecting those ids? Or what's that line_data? Finally, how is $IFS and OLD_IFS is working? I know these could be very basic questions; I am not that expert in Unix.

Comment: @Rookie_Guy `line_data` is a variable defined loop that holds the content of the string separated by `$IFS`. `IFS` is the built-in variable in the bash shell that defines the internal field separator: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSREF . The script stores the previous IFS before changing it before setting it back at the end.